# .htaccess setting for handling index files, trailing slashes, and file extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My website is pretty standard containing a bunch of index files inside folders. ie:

```
 folder1
      > index.php
      > some-file.php
      sub-folder1
           > index.php
      sub-folder2
           > index.php
 folder2
      > some-file.html
 index.html
```

I recently made some .htaccess changes that were supposed to allow a user to enter a file name without the .html extension but, still be directed to the correct file on the server.  It was also supposed to remove trailing slashes.  This is the code in my root .htaccess file:

```
 DirectoryIndex index.html
 RewriteEngine On

 # remove trailing slash
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
 #RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

 # To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

This seems to work fine with html files.  such as including a link to:

`folder2/some-file`

However, when I link to `folder1/` where the index file is a php file, I'm directed to a list of files and folders inside folder1.  I would expect the behavior to pull up `index.php` not the file list.

If I include the entire path in a link such as: `folder1/index.php` it works just fine.

This behavior all changed when I added the .htaccess setting above.  Before this I didn't even have a .htaccess file on my site.  I'm assuming it had to do with the code inside the .htaccess file but, I have no idea how to fix it, as the code it something I found on a help forum.

I also noticed that before I changed my .htaccess setting I could link to my root `index.html` from any page and the browser would just display `www.domain.com`.  now it always shows `www.domain.com/index`

Wondering if anyone knows the correct setting I should be using inside my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made `DirectoryIndex index.html` and if there is no `index.html` in directory ,listing will be done even there is `index.php` there .

Add it like this :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html  index.php
```

So , if there is no `index.html` request to directory will go to `index.php` .